# Struts2 - select box inside of an iterator - how to pass value when link outside of select box is clicked

Tags: javascript, struts2

I have an iterator that creates rows of data.  One column contains a link to an action.  Another column is a select box.  I can't for the life of me get the value selected in the select box to pass as a parameter when the link is clicked.  I've tried javascript and I get the correct value inside of the function but it isn't passing as a parameter when the link is clicked.  I'm missing something but I can't figure out what.

```
<s:iterator var="permit" value="permitsList" status="status" >
    <tr class="<s:if test="#status.even">even</s:if><s:else>odd</s:else>">
        <td style="text-align: center"> 
            <s:url var="dataEntryURL" action="processPermitSelectedSuccess">
                <s:param name="permitInfo.mepdesNumber" value="permitsList[#status.index].mepdesNumber" />
                <s:param name="permitInfo.facilityName" value="permitsList[#status.index].permitHistoryList[0].facilityName" />
NOTE: If permitInfo.outfallNumber is set to a value; the parameter and value are tacked onto the URL.  Using the following code, there is no parameter or value for permitList.outfallNumber included on the URL.
                <s:param name="permitInfo.outfallNumber" value="permitsList[%{#status.index}].selectedOutfall}" />
            </s:url>
            <s:a href="%{dataEntryURL}">
                <s:property value="permitsList[#status.index].mepdesNumber" />
            </s:a>
        </td>
        <td style="text-align: left">
            <s:property value="permitsList[#status.index].permitHistoryList[0].facilityName" />
        </td>
        <td style="text-align: center; white-space: nowrap" >
            <s:if test="permitsList[#status.index].outfallsList.size() > 1">
                <s:if test="permitsList[#status.index].selectedOutfall == null" >
                    <s:set var="permitsList[#status.index].selectedOutfall" value="permitsList[#status.index].defaultOutfall" />
                </s:if>
                <s:select theme="simple" 
                    name="permitsList[#status.index]selectedOutfall"
                    id="permitsList[#status.index]selectedOutfall"
                    list="permitsList[#status.index].outfallsList"
                    listKey="outfallsPK.outfallNumber" 
                    listValue="outfallsPK.outfallNumber"
                   value="permitsList[#status.index].selectedOutfall"
                    onchange="javascript: setOutfall(this.value)">
                </s:select>
            </s:if>
            <s:else>
                <s:property value="permitsList[#status.index].defaultOutfall" />
            </s:else>
        </td>
    </tr>
</s:iterator>
```

The javascript I'm using:

```
function setOutfall(selectedValue)
{
    // Using setTimeout() in this way forces IE to use a separate thread
    // for the .focus() function instead of processing at the same time
    // as it's own browser behaviour.
    alert("inside setOutfall() - selectedValue: " + selectedValue);

    setTimeout
    (function()
    {
        try
        {
            document.getElementsByName('permitsList[#status.index].selectedOutfall').value = selectedValue;
            alert("correctValue: " +     document.getElementsByName('permitsList[#status.index].selectedOutfall').value);           
        }
        catch(err)
        {
            txt="There was an error on this page.\n\n";
            txt+="Error description: " + err.message + "\n\n";
            txt+="Click OK to continue.\n\n";
            alert(txt);
        }
    }   
    , 50);
}
```

Please help!  Thanks

Comment: Search for "permitsList[#status.index]selectedOutfall" it should probably be "permitsList[#status.index].selectedOutfall" for the name attribute, remove the id attribute and let it figure it self out and use the cssClass attribute to set a class and get the values using the class (you'll probably find jQuery useful here).

Comment: jquery doesn't recognize your parameter, you should do this: `document.getElementsByName('<s:property value="permitsList[#status.index].selectedOutfall"').value = selectedValue;`